# How to change router settings page password on Huawei echolife EG8141A5?

Tags: router, passwords, administrator, optical-network-terminal

I have FTTH connection at my home. My GPON device is Huawei EG8141A5 (echolife). I cannot figure how I can change the password of the router settings page (192.168.100.1). Can someone help?

Comment: Are you looking to change the default user's password or your WiFi password?

Comment: There are 2 users: 'root' and 'telecomadmin'. I could change password of 'root' user. But could not find the other.

Comment: Sounds like you are purposefully unable to do so in that case.  Is this leased hardware by your ISP? The second user isn’t a default user which means it was added by your ISP.

Comment: Yes. The router is provided by the ISP. The password for the root user is printed under the router. But the guy from my provider used 'telecomadmin'. So can we do anything about it?

Comment: As I said it’s likely likely purposely configured to avoid that situation by your ISP.  Your ISP would have to provide that capability. That also isn’t one of the user names Huawei documented in the manual

Comment: Oh okay. Actually, there was no manual. It was just a modem and a power cable inside the box. No manual. No regulatory stuff and all. Just that.

Comment: Online the manual is online. I literally read the manual.l for the device

Comment: Ok. Anyway, thank you for your kind help.